# headnodehost in Azure HDInsights

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

What is this headnodehost in Azure HDinsights? I setup a HBase cluster. There are headnodes in this HBase cluster. When I RDP to the cluster and open the Hadoop Name Node status weblink from the desktop, it opens web browser with link set to headnodehost:30070. Is the headnodehost the same as the headnodes? The hostname command in the RDP gives me "headnode0" rather than "headnodehost".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each HDInsight cluster has two headnodes for high availability. It is documented in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-high-availability/

Comment: I read that document. It says HBase cluster has two headnodes. They are headnode0 and headnode1. So is there a VM named "headnodehost" as displayed in the "hadoop name node status" shortcut?

Comment: I figured that headnodehost will map to either headnode0 or headnode1, depending on which one is active.